# How to capture typing after a specific key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I need to capture typing before it is typed into a textbox and edit it to my needs. I write in javascript and jQuery.
I have a text box, and I want to detect when the "#" character is typed - before it is written into the text box - and then capture all the typing that comes afterwards (also before it is written) until I get another "#".

I have seen many examples online on how yo use "keypress" to detect when specific key is typed, but I don't know how to capture all the text that's being typed between the 2 special keys before it is written into the textbox.

I can use any help on the topic!

Comment: what have you tried? " I have seen many examples online on how yo use "keypress" to detect when specific key is typed" thats a good start, please show what you have

Comment: @atmd - what I meant was that I know how to handle keypress, what I had trouble with was capturing the text afterwards. that's why "preventDefualt" was an exellent solution, I didn't know about it. thanks vanojx1 and Ben Philipp! both of your answers were right on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this first case the input is prevented for all characters and then inside the text var you can edit and then assign a value to the input field

```
$('#typehere').on("keypress",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.which == "#".charCodeAt(0)){

        if(listening){
            listening= false;
            //do what you want with the text
            alert("no more listening: "+text);
        }else{
            listening = true;
            alert("listening"); 
        } 
        return true;
    }

    if(listening)
        text+= String.fromCharCode(e.which);
});
```

try the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/42fns28a/

in the second case you can type in the input field until your special char is pressed, you type and edit what you want until the special char is pressed the second time

```
$('#typehere').on("keypress",function(e){

    if(e.which == "#".charCodeAt(0)){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(listening){
            listening= false;
            //do what you want with the text
            $(this).val($(this).val()+text);
            alert("no more listening: "+text);
        }else{
            listening = true;
            alert("listening"); 
        } 
        return true;
    }

    if(listening){
        e.preventDefault();
        text+= String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    }
});
```

second fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2cdjoq6u/

Comment: This prevents ALL inputs... keys pressed when not "in between" hashes are ignored. You might want to add comments to your script so the OP can figure out what to do when this isn't desired

Comment: mmm ok i can explain this better

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventdefault()` to prevent the keys being written.
Check if you are "in between" hashes and just record the keys if that's the case (write them to string)
When you're 'leaving' a hash wrap, do something with the string.

**Check the JSFiddle below** for a more verbose example!

```js
var inhash=false;
var tmpstring="";
$("#editme").on("keypress", function(e){
    if(e.which==35){    // 35 is the keycode value for the hash symbol "#"
        e.preventDefault();   //don't send the key to the textarea
        inhash=!inhash;     // toggle the state of our "inhash" variable
        if(inhash==false){
            alert(tmpstring);   // if we just left a hash sequence, do something with it
            tmpstring="";   // don't forget to empty our record string
        }
    }else if(inhash==true){
        e.preventDefault();
        tmpstring+=String.fromCharCode(e.which);  // when we're "in between" hash symbols, write the key to our recording variable
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='editme'></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/yhzp3ob3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
});
```

link here: https://api.jquery.com/keypress/
credits to [admd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644786/atmd)

```js
$( "#target" ).change(function() {
  console.log("test input changed");
});
```

link here: https://api.jquery.com/change/